# attribute selectors contains meta-characters in jquery

Tags: jquery

In jquery **1.4.2** this was a valid selector:

```
$('input[name=test[0]]')
```

in jquery **1.6.2** it is not a valid selector, the docs state to escape special characters with \.

my question is, in what version did this happen, and can someone provide a link to a discussion of this change?

Comment: ...I don't want to appear judgemental, but: *...why?* This is, as written, [off-topic for Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/).

Comment: feel free to downvote and close, ill take my chances to get an answer

Comment: I do; but I was wondering if there's a specific programming-related aspect to your question that hadn't been fully explained, or that I was somehow missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector you posted does [**not** work in jQuery 1.4.4, but does work in 1.4.2](http://jsfiddle.net/YPd4J/)

See here for complete tests: http://jsfiddle.net/YPd4J/

Summary:

- `input[name=test[0]]` error in 1.6.2, doesn't work in 1.4.4, works in 1.4.2
- `input[name="test[0]"]` works in all versions
- `input[name=test\\[0\\]]` works in 1.6.2 & 1.4.2, not in 1.4.4
- `input[name="test\\[0\\]"]` works in all versions

I can remember the advise regarding escaping meta-characters been in the documentation as long as I can remember (and I've been using jQuery since 1.3.x)... maybe it was never **officially** supported, but just happened to work.

**Edit: Did the tests for 1.4.4, and then saw you actually wrote 1.4.2... tests updated :P**

Comment: **Always** quote your attribute values, it will help relieve headaches.

Comment: It's worth noting that, for the [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), quoting the value is 'mandatory' (from the API).